# How can I catch fish consistently in Treasures of Nadia?

Tags: treasure-of-nadia

Until now I could a lot of catch common fish like Rockfish and Seaperch and a few Hammerheads and Tunas.

Is there a way to catch rarer fish consistently?

In order to unlock other lures than natural and green jigs and plugs, the Bait shop owner wants me to catch a 50lb Marlin. I have only seen one Marlin in 2 hours of fishing and it broke one of my lures.

Is there a consistent way of catching fish? Are they more attracted to some lures and shy to others?

Where should I throw my fishing line at the beach? Mid or upper/lower end or does it matter at all?

Comment: How appropriate :)

Comment: Plenty of fish in the sea, so to speak :)